# How can I make a Custom UITableViewCell top cell draw uniquely after reuse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

So I've made some custom table view cells and they draw correctly and look great, however once I scroll past the edge of the visible cells they start being reused, which is fine, except that when I scroll back the reused cells are still shown and don't redraw.  Specifically all the cells look the same except for the top-most cell.

Pictures detailing the occurrence:

[image: desired] [image: then scroll down]
[image: then scroll up][image: and the issue]

How I have this coded up, is when the cells get made if the indexPath.row is greater than 0 add an "overlap effect" which is just a gradient on a uiview placed underneath the custom drawing on the UITableViewCell's contentView.

This is how I add the overlap effect in the UITableViewController's tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"APostCell";
  PostCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  // Configure the cell...
  CustomPost *aPost = [self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  if (indexPath.row > 0) {
    [cell addOverlap];
  }
  cell.postDateLabel.text = [aPost datePostedAsString];
  return cell;
}
```

How would I implement this [cell removeOverlap]?

Comment: where you create the cell if cell == nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after I posted the question I figured it out and, since I had the question and had previously not found any information on the subject figured I would share.

So whenever

```
PostCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]
```

is called, the table view either creates a new cell or reuses an old one.  When a new cell is created and it is not the top cell (indexPath.row == 0) it adds the overlap to the UITableViewCell.  And if it reuses the cell, that method still gets called, regardless what cell is being reused.  So naturally once the cell created at the top is reused, the gradient view still gets added to cell.contentView and it stays there even when I'm reusing for the topmost cell again.

In fact adding the overlap view in this way will stack multiple overlap views into the same cell.

So what has to be done (if you intend to customize the cell appearance this way) is to remove the added views **before each reuse** of the cell. So you have to overwrite the custom tableviewcell's prepareForReuse method and do just that like so.

```
- (void) prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self removeOverlap];
}
```

Be **SURE** the cell has the overlap view otherwise your app will break by trying to remove views not there. so have something like

```
- (void) removeOverlap {
    if ([self.contentView.subviews count] > 1) {

        //This method works based on the assumption [cell addOverlap] adds new view
        //underneath existing views - like [self.contentView insertSubview:overlappedView atIndex:0];
        [[self.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
   //remove overlap here

} else {

    [cell addOverlap];
}
```

beacuse, except 1st cell all have overlap.On scrolling the reused cell have the overlap. So for first cell remove the overlap if present.

Comment: This doesn't work how you would expect, whenever a cell is reused [cell addOverlap]; is called and a new overlap view is added to the cell so they stack up really quick, and they are only removed when the top cell comes around again

Comment: in `addOverlap` you can check there is already an overlap exist or not. As per your solution, except for first cell you removes and add overlap. is this really required.? just remove the overlap (if exist) at `(indexPath.row == 0)` and add overlap (if not) otherwise.